# react-router can't jump to the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom for my project, but I am a new to it. I have a problem about page jump, Here is my code for App.js:

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/userrestaurant"
            render={props => <UserRestaurant {...props} />}
          />
          <Route path="/userrestaurant/edit/:id" component={EditRestaurant} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is code for UserRestaurant component:

```
 export default class UserRestaurant extends Component {
  edit = () => {
    var restId = 4;
    this.props.history.push(`/userrestaurant/edit/${restId}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.edit}>Edit</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It suppose to jump to EditRestaurant component if I click Edit button since I have already define the Route in App.js. But when I click the button, only the url change, the page stay in the UserRestaurant component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<Route/>` does a partial match on URLs unless you add an [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop. In other words, `/userrestaurant/edit/blah` still matches the first case of the `Switch`, so `UserRestaurant` is still rendered. Either add `exact` so the first one doesn't still match the second URL or reorder your routes so the more specific one comes first.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/userrestaurant"
            exact
            component={UserRestaurant}
          />
          <Route 
            path="/userrestaurant/edit/:id" 
            component={EditRestaurant} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```